# How to import javascript files to reactjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, import, components

I used to import directly in index.html of public folder,  or used helmet node module. And I used to import javascript files in useEffect() of react component. But sometimes I faced errors while loading page. If you know another way to import js files to react component, please post answer.

I tried like this
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

```
<Helmet>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://knowme.tn/logo1.png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo3.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/mondeo/css/master.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/revolution/css/settings.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/revolution/js/layers.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/revolution/js/navigation.js"/>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using react-helmet module is the best way to import js files in reactjs.